# django allauth : how can I get linkedin data - r_basicprofile, position_fields, location_fields

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using `django-allauth==0.35.0` for sociallogin. (only linkedin, using `OAUTH 2.0`)

Based on Linkedin developers documentation, (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) I tried to get Basic Profile Fields (`r_basicprofile` in allauth), also Location Fields and Position Fields if possible.

I add `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` in `settings.py` like below,

(I'm not sure how to add location and position, so I tried to add them below `PROFILE_FIELDS`)

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'linkedin': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'r_emailaddress',
            'r_basicprofile',
            'r_fullprofile',
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first-name',
            'last-name',
            'positions',
            'email-address',
            'picture-url',
            'public-profile-url',
            'headline',
            'skills',
            'summary',
            'location',
            'industry',
            'positions',
            'company',
            'specialties',
            'public-profile-url',
        ],
        'LOCATION_FIELDS': [
            'location',
        ],
        'POSITION_FIELDS': [
            'company',
        ]
    }
}
```

Wierd thing is, when I got linkedin data, there's much missing fields. I only got `emailAddress`, `firstName`, `id`, `LastName`, `publicProfileUrl`, `id`. (here's `sociallogin.serialize().get('account')`)

```
{'account': {'date_joined': None,
  'extra_data': {'emailAddress': 'my_email@email.com',
   'firstName': 'myname',
   'id': 'xxxxx',
   'lastName': 'kim',
   'publicProfileUrl': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxx'},
  'id': None,
  'last_login': None,
  'provider': 'linkedin_oauth2',
  'uid': 'xxxx',
  'user_id': None},
 'email_addresses': [{'email': 'my_email@email.com',
   'id': None,
   'primary': True,
   'user_id': None,
   'verified': False}],
 'state': {'auth_params': '', 'process': 'login', 'scope': ''},
 'token': {'account_id': None,
  'app_id': 2,
  'expires_at': '2018-07-02T09:55:32.620Z',
  'id': None,
  'token': 'xxx',
  'token_secret': ''},
```

I found much more field in Basic Profile Fields offered from linkedin (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) such as headline, summary, and so on. But nothing comes.

What did I missing? Is there something to do more? How can I get all data from linkedin?

p.s. I grant all auth in my linkedin apps (r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin, w_share)

I appreciate any help.